# Unexpected result while reading encoded (Arabic) data from SQL Server using RODBC

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, dataframe, encoding

RODBC: reading encoded (Arabic) data from SQL Server to R dataframe shows "????" as the data instead of actual data. I'm trying to read the address(which is in Arabic) from the SQL Server Database, and then I need to compare the texts and do some calculations based on it. I'm reading the data to a dataframe using sqlquery in R. All the address data in the dataframe is question marks only(for example: عنوان is stored/displayed as ???????). Furthermore, I need to update this data back in the DB, it won't work there as well.

I've the following code:

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=xyz;database=abc;
trusted_connection=true;DBMSencoding = "UTF-8"');

query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col= '",value,"'");

DB <- sqlQuery(con, query,stringsAsFactors=FALSE);
```

Comment: pls add some information to your question like: what are you trying to achieve? what happens? any error?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see if it's clear now. Plus I don't get any error, a particular column which has the "location address" in arabic comes out to be as question marks("?????").